# Multisite or multiple sites setup with Open ID server

Tags: 7, multi-sites, authentication-authorization

I am working on a project where I have a basic site with a sets of modules and configurations. Currently when I get a new client for this project in order for him/her to use their own site, I setup a subdomain, load a basic DB and copy the basic site files over.

This setup has work for me, but now I am having to deal with more clients and the manual process will just make it hard to manage and maintain. Ideally I will love to have it a single set of files will connect each user DB and I don't care if instead of subdomains (they are nicer) I have to use sub-directories.

What will be best for this setup multisite or multiple sites, and will it make sense to have a centralize account (open id) server?

> **Note:** I was thinking in register the users in a single place and then they can login into their private sites using this centralize
>   account system. Otherwise each site will have to have a user 1 account
>   with a password to be manage for each site.

Thank you

Comment: Will each sub-site need it's own user base or just the client admin account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use multisite to run about 50 Drupal sites from a single code base, but each site has its own database.

To be able to manage all the site, I use the [Drupal Remote Dashboard Server module](https://www.drupal.org/project/drd_server) and its corresponding Drupal Remote Dashboard module. These modules let me out all the servers into maintenance mode, or run update.php.

Comment: Does each site has a user 1 plus any other user or do you use something like Open ID to have a centralize account directory? Do you have modules in one of the sites that you don't use in another?

Comment: Each site has its own User1 (me), but the Drupal Remote Dashboard Server module take care of logging you in to them all.

Each site has its own set of modules, installed into its /site/sitename.com/modules directory.

Comment: Do you share any tables between the site databases? Do you have the sites as sub domains or directories of the main site?

Comment: Each site has its own database, to ensure data integrity. Each site has its own full domain.

Answer (score 1):

I think multisite would work well if you're keeping all of the same code.  I know you can do it with subdomains (or even completely different domains) using the sites.php file, I'm not so sure about sub-directories.

Have a look at the [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module which will allow you to import all of your standard settings as a single module on new sites.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I have been avoiding Features like the plague waiting for the file configuration system on D8 and/or Backdrop.

Comment: That's what I have right now a basic site with the modules and the DB configuration that I copy over the newly created subdomain. The question about Open ID is just to learn if it will make sense or not to use it with such setup.

Comment: I was thinking in register the users in a single place and then they can login into their private sites using this centralize account system. Otherwise each site will have to have a user 1 account with a password to be manage.

Comment: Best update your question with that, people might miss it in the comments =)

Comment: Good point. I just did that. Once again, thank you.